# C++ Use of enum '___' without previous declaration in header file?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use enums to represent streets and directions in a traffic simulation. I'm running into an issue of trying to include in my Vehicle header file putting the enums in the constructor and putting it into the Vehicle constructor.

I get the error when I try to compile Vehicle.h 
 - use of enum 'street/direction' without previous declaration. 
 - and two expected identifier before ',' token where I declare Vehicle constructor

Here is what I have so far.

```
//Street.h

#ifndef STREET_H
#define STREET_H

enum street
{
    Main = 1,
    Church,
};

#endif

//Direction.h

#ifndef DIRECTION_H
#define DIRECTION_H

enum direction
{
    E = 1,
    W,
    N,  
};

#endif

//Vehicle.h

#ifndef VEHICLE_H  
#define VEHICLE_H

#include "Street.h"
#include "Direction.h"

class Vehicle
{
   private:
    int vehicleNumber;
    int arrivalTime;
    int departureTime;
    enum street;
    enum direction;

   public:
    Vehicle(int, enum, enum, int);
};

#endif
```

Comment: `Vehicle(int, enum, enum, int);` you should put the name of the enum type, instead of the keyword enum (i.e. street, direction)

Comment: Also, you have extra commas after the last enum values in your declarations.

Comment: @dwcanillas Extra trailing commas are not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vehicle(int, enum, enum, int);`

This is incorrect, you should be using the name of the enum type you want (in this case `street` and `direction` *not* the keyword `enum`.

Same goes for those member variables (thanks to @Unda for noticing).

Comment: He also seems to wrongly declare the last 2 private fields.

Comment: @Unda How are they wrongly declared? Just starting out on C++. How would I declare them correctly?

Comment: @battleskies Just as Bordleader said, you replace `enum` by the actual name of the enum type. Here: `street streetMemberName; direction directionMemberName;`